# Linux Startup Script + add one command

Tags: linux, redhat

I need one command line to run at startup. I've tested the command (it re-assosiates an Amazon IP to a Linux Server) and the command run successfully.

Just need to know the best method to execute this on server reboot? The server is RedHat and I've read a bit about /etc/init.d but still unsure.

command is:

```
ec2-associate-address -v -i i-xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --region ap-southeast-1 -O key -W secret
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Script on EC2 Boot](http://serverfault.com/questions/301918/running-script-on-ec2-boot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the script file has exectable flag

```
  chmod filename.sh +x
```

I would recommend putting it in /etc/rc.local.  Also, make sure there is a

```
  &
```

at the end of the line of the script so that it runs in the background and doesn't stop other things from running.