# ec2-associate-address + how to run on Linux Startup

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux Startup Script + add one command](https://serverfault.com/questions/431930/linux-startup-script-add-one-command)

I have an ec2-associate-address command line that reassigns an EIP to EC2 successfully when I run it from the command line.

I've put this command line into /etc/rc.local but it doesn't re-assign the EIP - it remains a EC2 Public address (that changes each reboot)...

Note: the script is using and IAM user with assign IP rights and this works fine so long as I run it myself. Also Note: if I excute sudo /etc/rc.local it also assigns the IP.

Is the script running to early by chance?

What else could be preventing this from working?

Does rc.local run as root?

Comment: Try adding the full path of the executable, i.e.  /usr/bin/ec2-associate-address or wherever it is.  Use which to find its location.

Comment: actually its not a duplicate - if you read it more closly - the inital was about where to place the command and this was having trouble with it not running on startup... best read closer there boys...